# What was Armando Dippet's education specialty?

Tags: harry-potter

We know that Dumbledore (and McGonagall) were both Transfiguration Professors before becoming Headmaster/Headmistress.

What was Armando Dippet teaching before becoming Headmaster?

Any level of canon acceptable.

Comment: Good question! I can't find any JKR-approved information, and can't think of anywhere to look. Depending on how loose your definition of canon is, [this fanfic](http://www.harrypotterfanfiction.com/viewstory.php?chapterid=207710) reckons Potions :D

Comment: @luna sorry, no fanfics :-)

Answer (score 1):

**We don't know.**

There isn't any information in the canon books, additional materials, pottermore, films, video games, frog cards or JKR's old website that tells us what he taught at Hogwarts (or even if he taught at Hogwarts) prior to becoming Headmaster.

Unless there are future revelations about him, we'll have to remain clueless on this issue.

Comment: Would nobody dare tweet JKR? :)

Comment: @DVK - You can if you want to risk her revealing that he was actually a goblin.

Comment: sounds like you just got hired by Quibbler :)

Comment: @DVK - Nowhere in the books does it not say that Prof Dippett isn't a centaur.

Comment: Perhaps JKR got infected with Nargles?

Comment: Either that, or JJAbramasitis.

Comment: @DVK - She's gone full Lucas.

Comment: Are you saying that... Harry Shot First?

Comment: Also, in Blue-Ray edition of Harry Potter, all wands will be replaced by Walkie-Talkies